# How to read JPG images as CV_16UC1 and print on screen?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I want to read a `JPG` images as a `CV_16UC1` on `OpenCV` (in `C++`).

I can also convert from `CV_8UC3` to `CV_16UC1`.

This code below works, but here it's using only `CV_8UC3` format, which is not what I need:

```
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    Mat im1 = imread("MyPic.JPG");
    Mat im2 = imread("MyPic.JPG");
    Size sz1 = im1.size();
    Size sz2 = im2.size();

    Mat final(sz1.height, sz1.width + sz2.width, CV_8UC3);
    Mat left(final, Rect(0, 0, sz1.width, sz1.height));
    im1.copyTo(left);

    Mat right(final, Rect(sz1.width, 0, sz2.width, sz2.height));
    im2.copyTo(right);

    imshow("final", final);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
 }
```

But I need to use `CV_16UC1` (This is really **necessary**!). Therefore, I've converted like this:

```
    cv::Mat im2 = cv::imread("MyPic.jpg");
    cv::Size sz2 = im2.size();

    cv::Mat im3; // I want im3 to be the CV_16UC1 of im2
    im2.convertTo(im3, CV_16UC1);
    cv::Size sz3 = im3.size();

    cv::Mat im1 = cv::imread("MyPic.jpg");
    cv::Size sz1 = im1.size();

    cv::Mat im4;
    im4.convertTo(im1, CV_16UC1);
    cv::Size sz4 = im4.size();

    // Two images by each other side - this must be CV_16UC1
    cv::Mat final(sz1.height, sz1.width + sz2.width, CV_16UC1);

    // The left image
    cv::Mat left(final, cv::Rect(0, 0, sz1.width, sz1.height));
    im1.copyTo(left);

    // The right image
    cv::Mat right(final, cv::Rect(sz1.width, 0, sz2.width, sz2.height));
    im4.copyTo(right);

    cv::imshow("final", final);

    cv::waitKey(0);
```

It seems that I'm doing something wrong on the convertions or on the way I'm reading, because no image is appearing on the screen.

How can I convert correctly from `CV_8UC3` to `CV_16UC1`?

Comment: Can you take a step back and maybe explain *why* you believe you need to make a 16-bit image from an 8-bit JPEG? There may be other options that would suit your needs better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 8-Bit-Unsigned Mat's pixel values range between 0 and 255, so, when you load the images from file and display them, each pixel will be brighter the closer it is to 255, the maximum value.

When you convert those images to 16Bit-Unsigned, the pixels will keep the same absolute value (something between 0 and 255), but now the maximum value of your data structure is 65535. So, it is no surprise at all that the images are dark. Even the higher value (255) will still be so low in the new resolution that it will look like it is not there.

> "How to read JPG images as CV_16UC1 and print on screen?"

You can't. The .jpg images just aren't CV_16UC1. If you generated those images and thought they would hold 16Bit data, they don't. Probably you didn't save it correctly. Once they are .jpg, they lose most the information they had and there is no magic way to recover it.

Comment: This answer really deserves some links to the docs of [`convertTo`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto) and [`imshow`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow), along with a quote of that essential sentence from the latter which explains what happens when you try to display a 16 bit image. ;) All the hints are out there, why don't so many people read it...

Comment: Thanks @Pedro Batista . Is there any way I can save an image as u16 type then?

Comment: @waas1919 you can save them using the the the opencv FileStorage object http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/da/d56/classcv_1_1FileStorage.html . Alternatively, you can use c++ fstream to save raw data directly to file.